# data showing undefined on useQuery

Tags: reactjs

The data is pulled by the api but when trying to call it in the react page it is undefined, I believe the error lies within the useQuery.
here is the useQuery code

```
  const { data: shopSplits, isLoading: SSL } = useQuery(
    ["Shopsplits", { Active: 0 }],
    ShopSplits
  );
  console.log("the splits", shopSplits)
```

here is the api call

```
export const ShopSplits = async ({queryKey}) =>{
   try {
      const {id, Active } = queryKey[1]
      //&ShopGrouping=${ShopGrouping}&Location=${Location}&Active=${Active}
      const res = await axios.get(`/api/ShopSplits?id=${id}IsActive=${Active}`)
      console.log(res)
      const data = res.data
      console.log( data)
      return data.data
      
     } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      
     } 
}
```

Comment: Add some more information on what you've tried so far, and what do you receive from the res, data objects. There's not enough information to know what the issue is

Answer (score 0):

I was returning data.data, when in fact it was supposed to be data.
Quite a stupid error.

```
export const ShopSplits = async ({queryKey}) =>{
   try {
      const {id, Active } = queryKey[1]
      //&ShopGrouping=${ShopGrouping}&Location=${Location}&Active=${Active}
      const res = await axios.get(`/api/ShopSplits?id=${id}IsActive=${Active}`)
      console.log(res)
      const data = res.data
      console.log( data)
      return data
      
     } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      
     } 
}
```